# How to visualize data from a 6-axis gyroscope using a 3D model in WPF?

Tags: wpf, gyroscope, 3d-model

I have a PS4 game controller, and I can now read data from it using HID, including 6 axes as shown in the image below.

[image: 6-axis data]

Three axes represent acceleration, and the other three represent angular rate.

With this data, I should be able to visualize the actual posture of the controller using a 3D model in WPF. Currently, I found that the "3D Controller Overlay" feature in Steam perfectly achieves the effect I desire. Is there any library or framework available to help achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found [this](https://github.com/xioTechnologies/Open-Source-AHRS-With-x-IMU/blob/master/x-IMU%20IMU%20and%20AHRS%20Algorithms/x-IMU%20IMU%20and%20AHRS%20Algorithms/AHRS/MadgwickAHRS.cs) solution which perfectly solved my problem. Create a instance of `MadgwickAHRS`, then call `Update` to update the six-axis data, and finally obtain a quaternion for rotation. The specific code is as follows:

```cs
static MadgwickAHRS AHRS = new MadgwickAHRS(4f / 1000f, 0.1f);
static float deg2rad(float degrees)
{
    return (float)(Math.PI / 180) * degrees;
}
private void OnSensorDataUpdated(byte[] hidData){
    short gyroX = BitConverter.ToInt16(hidData[13]), 
        gyroY = BitConverter.ToInt16(hidData[15]), 
        gyroZ = BitConverter.ToInt16(hidData[17]), 
        accelX = BitConverter.ToInt16(hidData[19]), 
        accelY = BitConverter.ToInt16(hidData[21]), 
        accelZ = BitConverter.ToInt16(hidData[23]);
    //Since my gyro data is in degrees, it needs to be converted to radians
    AHRS.Update(deg2rad(gyroX), deg2rad(gyroY), deg2rad(gyroZ), accelX, accelY, accelZ);
    var rotation = new Quaternion(AHRS.Quaternion[1], AHRS.Quaternion[2], AHRS.Quaternion[3], AHRS.Quaternion[0]);
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
        var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D();
        rotateTransform.Rotation = new QuaternionRotation3D(rotation);
        YourModel.Transform = rotateTransform;//Update to ModelVisual3D
    });
}
```